# Style listview selected item in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

How can I style listview selected item in XAML in Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the style of the template ListViewItem which the ListView generates for each of the items that it renders. Your updated template needs to customise the Selected visual state. You can then associate this new template with your ListView via the ListView.ItemContainerStyle property.

Blend can be very helpful with this.